# Creating a dashboard using csv files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, highcharts, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard using CSV files, Highcharts.js, and HTML5. In a local development environment I can render the charts using CSVs both on my file system and hosted on the web. The current goal is to deploy the dashboard live on Heroku.

The CSVs will be updated manually - for now - once per day in a consistent format as required by Highcharts. The web application should be able to render the charts with these new, "standardized" CSVs whenever the dashboard page is requested. My question is: **where do I host these CSVs?** Do I use S3? Do I keep them on my local file system and manually push the updates to heroku daily? If the CSVs are hosted on another machine, is there a way for my application (and only my application) to access them securely?

Thanks!

Comment: Security should not really be an issue since the values will be view-able by anyone using the charts. Access to the CSVs should be done on a `Session` basis on the site itself, aka when people login to your site. Edit and upload manually or directly on the server, that's really a personal preference. (Make a script?)

Comment: In general, csv should be placed on the webserver, becuase $.get() function needs to public url to load file. Hope that it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the gem carrierwave direct to upload the file directly from the client to an Amazon S3 bucket.

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct

You basically give the trusted logged in client a temporary key to upload the file, and nothing else, and then the client returns information about the uploaded file to your web app. Make sure you have set the upload to be private to prevent any third parties from trying to brut force find the CSV. You will then need to create a background worker to do the actually work on the CVS file. The gem has some good docs on how to do this.

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct#processing-and-referencing-files-in-a-background-process

In short in the background process you will download the file temporarily to heroku, parse it out, get the data you need and then discard the copy on heroku, and if you want the copy on S3. This way you get around the heroku issue of permanent file storage, and the issue of tied up dynos with direct uploads, because there is nothing like NGINX for file uploads on heroku.

Also make sure that the file size does not exceed the available memory of your worker dyno, otherwise you will crash. Sense you don't seem to need to worry about concurrency I would suggest https://github.com/resque/resque.